# How to lease tasks from a pull-queue when running in dev_appserver?

Tags: google-app-engine, pull-queue, dev-appserver

Is there a way to lease tasks from a  pull-queue when running the application locally using dev_appserver?

More Info:

I have a GAE app that uses pull queues. I need to lease tasks from that queue from a different service written in java. I am running the GAE app using dev_appserver on my machine. How do I lease tasks from this queue? The Docs on GAE state that I have to lease tasks by hitting a REST endpoint on https://www.googleapis.com/taskqueue/v1beta1/projects/taskqueues. This URI is not exposed by my machine.

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Maybe an example of what you are trying to do.

Comment: I edited my question to add the context.

Comment: Hi @feroze, I am running into the same problem now and wondering you got any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

If the development server doesn't expose the endpoint, you'll have to build a minimal implementation of it yourself in order to test it.

But maybe a better approach would be to build a mock implementation the Java service could connect to (and be tested against) instead of requiring a running dev_appserver instance. This also has the advantage of keeping your implementation simple, as it doesn't have to think much and actually manage queues, but only respond according to what the Google endpoint would. You could also simulate any error conditions you experience from Google to see if your Java services can deal with those situations correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will get the backend URL , no mater its cloud or local devserver

```
    BackendService backendsApi = BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService();
    log.info( "Well we have a backend {}", backendsApi.getBackendAddress( "backendName" ) );
```